# Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> в IReadOnlyDictionary<int, IReadOnlyDictionary<int, string>>

Tags: c#

У меня внутри класса есть приватное поле:

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>
```

Наружу хочется возвращать:

```
IReadOnlyDictionary<int, IReadOnlyDictionary<int, string>>
```

Пытался кастовать:

```
(IReadOnlyDictionary<int, IReadOnlyDictionary<int, string>>) Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>
```

Но ругается...

Comment: а чего кастовать, это ж разные классы. `var myReadOnlyDict = new ReadOnlyDictionary<K, V>(myDictionary);`

Comment: Dictionary реализует интерфейс IReadOnlyDictionary

Comment: "На ружу" -> "в нутрь"

Comment: Как именно пытались кастовать? Внутренний словарь тоже кастовали? Приложите код, чтобы было о чём говорить.

Comment: действительно не кастуется (причем выясняется это только в момент выполнения). советовать создавать новый объект не буду (безопасность не стоит того).

Comment: явный каст не получится, это же дженерики, если подойдет, то есть рабочее решение с использованием LiNQ и некоторым оверхедом по памяти, если исходный словарь большой, то увы.

Comment: Как именно ругается - тоже добавьте в вопрос. Странно, что при таком вашем рейтинге приходится вам объяснять, как задать хороший вопрос :)